# How can I add bonus effects to a dice game in discord js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a question, which i wonder if it is even possible.
All the code works exactly how i want it to.
First, let me explain what my purpose is!

I have a fully functionnal script for my discord bot.
Basically, it is a dice game between 2 players with in stake a role chosen randomly between all the roles the player has. Each role will have a BONUS EFFECT and what i would like to do is to add this bonus effect to the game. In a manner, for example just before the player 1 pulls the first dice, ask him if he wants to activate his bonus or something like that.

The bot works this way : !fight usertag to start the game, click on a dice emoji to react and it rolls a 20 dice to determine the beginner,it sends a PM with the choosen role and his effect, and then each user has to react with a dice emoji to "inflict damages". I'll add an image for clarity:

[image: bot preview]

I will post here my code so you can see.

```js
const { ReactionCollector } = require('discord.js');
const request = require("./../config");
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const embed = new MessageEmbed();


function rolldice(numero){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * numero + 1);
}

function premier(msg,user){
  diceroll1 = rolldice(20)
  diceroll2 = rolldice(20)
  msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294,title:`Déterminons qui va commencer` ,description:`Un d20 a été lancer pour déterminer le premier à jouer.\n\n${msg.author.tag} a eu : ${diceroll1} \n\n ${user.tag} a eu : ${diceroll2}`}})


  if(diceroll1 > diceroll2){
    msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`${msg.author.tag} gagne et va donc commencer.`}})
    return msg.author.id
  }
  else if(diceroll1 < diceroll2){
    msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`${user.tag} gagne et va donc commencer.`}})
    return user.id
    
  }
  else{
    msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`Vous avez fait égalité. On recommence le tirage.`}})
    return premier(msg,user)
  }
}

function attaque1(msg, user){
  damagedice1 = rolldice(6)
  damagedice2 = rolldice(6)
  somme = damagedice1 + damagedice2
  return {somme,damagedice1,damagedice2}
}

async function bagarre(msg,user,w,v,x,y){
  const filter = (reaction,user) => [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id ===v;
  const reactOptions = {max : 1};
  const duel = await msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`${x} clique sur  pour lancer 2d6 pour determiner les dégats que tu vas infliger.`}})
  await duel.react('');

  const reactions = await duel.awaitReactions(filter, reactOptions);

  if(reactions.first().emoji.name === ''){
    var atksmme = attaque1(msg,user)
    w = w - atksmme.somme
    msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`${x} inflige ${atksmme.somme} de dégâts à ${y}! (${atksmme.damagedice1} + ${atksmme.damagedice2})`}})
    if(w > 0){
      msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`Il reste ${w} points de vie à ${y}`}})
    }
    else if(w<=0){
      msg.channel.send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`Il ne reste plus de points de vie à ${y}, il est finito.`}})
    }
    
    
  }
  return w
  }

module.exports = {
  name: 'fight',
  args :  true,
  usage : '@<user>',
  async execute(msg,args) {
    //VARIABLES
    const { client } = msg;
    var winner;
    var user1health = 12;
    var user2health = 12;

    //checks if the username to fight is in the msg
    var author1 = msg.author.username;
    var user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return msg.reply({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:"Tu n'as pas préciser contre qui tu veux te battre!"}});
    //checks if the users is trying to fight themselves
    if(user.id == msg.author.id) return msg.reply({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:'Tu ne peux pas te battre contre toi même!'}});
    //checks if the user is trying to fight the bot
    if(user.bot ==  true)
        return msg.reply({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:'Tu ne peux pas te battre contre un bot!'}});

    //saves the two user ids to variables
    var fighter1 = msg.author.id;
    var fighter2 = user.id;
    var challenged = user.toString();
    var fighter1tag = msg.author.tag;
    var fighter2tag = user.tag;


    const bataille = await msg.channel.send({ embed: {
      color: 0x407294, 
      author: {
        name: fighter1tag,
        icon_url: msg.author.avatarURL(),
      },
      description:`${challenged}, tu veux te battre?`}});
    await bataille.react('');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === fighter2;
    const reactOptions = {max : 1};

    const reponseAdversaire = await bataille.awaitReactions(filter,reactOptions);

    if(reponseAdversaire.first().emoji.name === ''){
      msg.channel.send({ embed: {
        color: 0x407294, 
        title:`Le combat peut commencer.`,
        fields : [
          {
            name: `Pdv de ${fighter1tag}`,
            value: user1health,
          },
          {
            name: `Pdv de ${fighter2tag}`,
            value: user2health,
          },
        ]
        }});


      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
      

      //MP THE PLAYER WITH THE ROLE AND ITS BONUS
      roles1 = msg.member.roles.cache.map(r => r.name).slice(0,-1)
      roles2 = msg.mentions.members.first().roles.cache.map(r => r.name).slice(0,-1)

      var roleFighter1 = roles1[Math.floor(Math.random()*roles1.length)];
      var roleFighter2 = roles2[Math.floor(Math.random()*roles2.length)];

      client.users.cache.get(fighter1).send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`Ton rôle en jeu est ${roleFighter1} et voici son effet: ${request.bonus[roleFighter1]}.\nTon adversaire ne le sait pas. Utilise cela à bon escient.`}})
      client.users.cache.get(fighter2).send({ embed: { color: 0x407294, description:`Ton rôle en jeu est ${roleFighter2} et voici son effet: ${request.bonus[roleFighter2]}.\nTon adversaire ne le sait pas. Utilise cela à bon escient.`}})

      //DETERMINE THE FIRST TO PLAY
      winner = premier(msg,user)

      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

      // START OF THE 1V1 LOOP
      if(winner === fighter1){
        while(user2health > 0){
        user2health = await bagarre(msg,user,user2health,fighter1,fighter1tag,fighter2tag);
        if(user2health <= 0){break};
        while(user1health > 0) {
          user1health = await bagarre(msg,user,user1health,fighter2,fighter2tag,fighter1tag);
          if(user1health <= 0){break};
          break;
          }
        if(user1health <= 0 || user2health <= 0) {break};
        }
      }
      else if(winner === fighter2){
        while(user1health > 0){
        user1health = await bagarre(msg,user,user1health,fighter2,fighter2tag,fighter1tag);
        if(user1health <= 0){break};
        while(user2health > 0) {
          user2health = await bagarre(msg,user,user2health,fighter1,fighter1tag,fighter2tag);
          if(user2health <= 0){break};
          break;
          }
        if(user1health <= 0 || user2health <= 0) {break};
        }
      }
    }
}}
```

And another file to have the bonuses

```js
var bonus = {
  '@Uchiha ️':"Changing the die value ",
  '@Akatsuki ☁️':"Pass the opponent's turn",
  '@Boss Passione ':"On the next turn, double the value of the dice",
  '@Révolutionnaire ':"Reduces the opponent's die value",
  '@SSJ3':"Swaps the value of the opponent's dice with that of the thrower",
  '@Spin ':"If the opponent has a rank in the Joestar category, heals the caster's HP by 4 and reduces the value of the opponent's next throw by 2",
  '@Empereur':"Allows to reuse the value of the previous dice roll",
  '@Kage':"Allows the value of the opponent's die to be canceled if it exceeds 4",
  '@Ruban Rouge':"Grants a second roll of the dice, the thrower can choose to keep the previous or the new one",
  '@Zeppeli':"If the opponent has a rank in the Joestar category, heals the caster's HP by 4 and reduces the value of the opponent's next throw by 2",
  '@Jinchuriki ':"Reflects damage caused by the opponent for 1 turn",
  '@Stand':"If the opponent has a rank in the Joestar category, heals the caster's HP by 4 and reduces the value of the opponent's next throw by 2",
  '@SSJ2':"If the opponent has a rank of the Saiyan category, increase the value of the die by 3",
  '@Jonin':"If the opponent has a rank in the Genin category, copy the maximum value of a dice roll made by the opponent and apply it to the thrower",
  '@Grand Corsaire':"Si l'adversaire possède un grade de la catégorie Joestar, soigne les PDV du lanceur de 4 et réduit la valeur du prochain lancer adverse de 2",
  '@SSJ':"If the opponent has a rank of the Saiyan category, increase the value of the die by 3",
  '@Chunin':"Grants a second roll of the dice, the thrower can choose to keep the previous or the new one ",
  '@Onde':"If the opponent has a rank in the Joestar category, heals the caster's HP by 4 and reduces the value of the opponent's next throw by 2 ",
  '@Supernova':"Changement de la valeur du dé ",
  '@Marine ⚓':"Changement de la valeur du dé ",
  '@Speedwagon':"If the opponent has a rank in the Joestar category, heals the caster's HP by 4 and reduces the value of the opponent's next throw by 2",
  '@Namek':"Changement de la valeur du dé ",
  
}


exports.bonus=bonus;
```

Big thanks to the one who's gonna try to help me!

Comment: Will a user ever have more than one of these "Special Effect" roles?

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach your friend's tile number in the next roll?

Create a function that takes your position a and your friend's position b and returns a boolean representation of whether it's possible to earn a bonus on any dice roll.

```js
function possBonus(a, b) {
  if(a === b || a+6 < b || a > b+6 || a>b) {
    return false;
  } else if(a-b <=6 || b-a <=6 ) {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(possBonus(5, 3));
```